# Create a right click option for list items in SWT

Tags: java, list, swt, contextmenu

I have created a `List` in a `TabFolder` and for that list of elements I want to have a right click option for each elements of the list. So how can this be done in SWT.

I have added the elements to the list as follows:

```
list.add("a");
list.add("b");
list.add("b");
list.add("v");
list.add("d");
list.add("l");
```

Now how can I create a right click option for this list for each element?

Answer (score 4):

This should be a good starting point:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final List list = new List(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    list.add("a");
    list.add("b");
    list.add("b");
    list.add("v");
    list.add("d");
    list.add("l");

    final Menu menu = new Menu(list);
    list.setMenu(menu);
    menu.addMenuListener(new MenuAdapter()
    {
        public void menuShown(MenuEvent e)
        {
            int selected = list.getSelectionIndex();

            if(selected < 0 || selected >= list.getItemCount())
                return;

            MenuItem[] items = menu.getItems();
            for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
            {
                items[i].dispose();
            }
            MenuItem newItem = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.NONE);
            newItem.setText("Menu for \"" + list.getItem(list.getSelectionIndex()) + "\"");
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]